# when running this code i am getting an exception how to solve this

Tags: java

i am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Calc.<init>(II)V
    at ex10thekeywords.main(ex10thekeywords.java:19)
```

```
class Calc
{
    int num1, num2, result;

    public Calc(int number1, int number2) 
    {
        num1 = number1;
        num2 = number2;
    }

}
```

```
public class ex10thekeywords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calc obj = new Calc(5, 5); // error pointing here as line 19

        System.out.println(obj.num1);
        System.out.println(obj.num2);

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you compile `Calc.java` before `ex10thekeywords`?

Comment: this code is working in the atom editor but not in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Create Calc.java and move the calc class into there, but make sure to make the calc class public.

Comment: Calc.java needs to be in the same package as ex10thekeywords and will need to be imported.

Comment: this code is working in the atom editor but not in eclipse